# How do you calculate phase shift induced by a shunt capacitor?

Tags: diodes, phase-shift, reactance, reflection, varactor

Given a simple loaded-line shunt-capacitor phase shifter, how can I calculate the phase shift and insertion loss at S21 caused by the shunt capacitor (varicap in my case, but for any cap) assuming I know the capacitance value C1?  I can model this in Sonnet (or perhaps some circuit theory program) but I want to put the calculations in a spreadsheet and see if my simulated model (nearly) matches the mathematical model.

[image: loaded line phase shifter]

1. According to [Rick Sturdivant](http://www.ricksturdivant.com/2016/07/09/varactophaseshifter/) the "normalized shunt susceptence" of the capacitor (\$B\$) must be known---but I can't find such a value on varicap/varactor datasheets.  If I can get \$B\$ then Rick says insertion loss is \$ 10\log_{10}({1+{B^2 \over 4}}) \$ and phase shift is \$-\tan^{-1}({B \over 2})\$.

- Can \$B\$ be calculated from the value of C(v)? I tried \$B = {1 \over X_c} = 2\pi f C\$ but my values don't line up to his unless his \$f\$ is about 100**GHz**, which seems unlikely.  (I'm shooting for a center frequency of 146MHz.)

2. At [microwaves101.com](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/varactor-phase-shifters) they hint that "the reflection coefficient from a shunt capacitor" might be used to calculate phase shift, in which case I don't need susceptence: \$ {\displaystyle \Gamma ={1-j2\pi fCZ_0 \over 1+j2\pi fCZ_0} } \$ .  But once I have \$\Gamma\$, how do I calculate shift?
3. and [Wikipedia:Reflection Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient) says that "if that load, \$Z_L\$ were measured not directly but through a transmission line, then [...] its phase will have shifted according to
   \$ {\displaystyle \Gamma '=\Gamma e^{-i\,2\phi }}\$ where ϕ [is phase]"---but I think thats the S11 reflection phase not the S21 phase.  Even if it is the S21 phase, how do I calculate \$\phi\$?

If you can help me understand what is right, what is irrelevant, and what other information I need to answer the question and how to calculate phase shift and insertion loss then I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Where is your schematic for this: *loaded-line shunt-capacitor phase shifter* - and what are the schematics you show? What relevance do they have?

Comment: As you show it it's a T filter. But what is `Zo` meant to represent: the output/input impedances, or some added elements to form a T filter, or what? And where do you measure, before and after the `Zo`, or in between, across the capacitor? Not lastly, what kind of impedances are those `Zo`, inductive, capacitive, both? If `Zo` is resistive or inductive, it's a lowpass overall, if it's capacitive, it's a voltage divider with phase shift (well, more than that, actually), if it's mixed it's complicated.

Comment: @Andyaka The schematic comes from here (the image is clickable): http://www.ricksturdivant.com/2016/07/09/varactophaseshifter/ .  It is relevant because The site linked indicates that a phase shift can be calculated from B, but how can I find B?  Or, alternatively, how do I calculate the phase shift of a shunt capacitor pulling a feedline to ground?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen,  Assume the Zo segments in the schematics are just feedlines with some characteristic impedance---50 ohms if you like.  The schematic has been updated to be more clear, there are no more confusing Zo segments, just S11 and S21 feedlines.

Comment: Perhaps I should note that numbered list 1,2,3 is the research I've done in case it sparks insight into the problem for the person answering, but I suppose the question itself could be posed without the numbered list at all.

Comment: You need to add more information about your circuit. We need to know the length from the source to the capacitor. Anyway, it is relatively straight forward to calculate using transmission line theory or you can use a Smith chart. Set your input wave to a sine wave; then phase shift as you travel to the capacitor; and finally use the reflection coefficient to work out the standing wave.

Comment: @user110971, what if we say that the length is L?  What do you mean by "phase shift as you travel to the capacitor"?  The phase on the way to the capacitor isn't shifting, isn't it just oscillating?